# Splatting a hashtable - Start-Process -ArgumentList

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to install an .MSI using splatting:

```
$InstallerArgs @{
    "DATABASENAME" = "my_database";
    "LOCALIP" = "127.0.0.1";
    "USERNAME" = "username1";
    "/i" = "C:\Files\Installer.msi";
}
```

I then call `Start-Process:`

```
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList @InstallerArgs -Wait
```

This returns the error: `Missing an argument for parameter 'ArgumentList'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try again.`

Is it not possible to use splatting with `Start-Process`?

Comment: It is possible to use splatting with `Start-Process` but you cannot provide the options for the msi installer this way.

Comment: As an aside, for those wondering whether the use of `Start-Process` is necessary here: it _is_, namely to ensure _synchronous_ (blocking) execution with the help of the `-Wait` switch. `msiexec`, despite having an extensive CLI, is _not_ a _console application_, and therefore by default executes _asynchronously_ (and always without console output).

Comment: If you're not running it from a script and just want to run the command to uninstall something from the PowerShell prompt, I prefer asynchronous because I get the prompt back and don't have to wait for the uninstall to finish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work actually:

```
$InstallerArgs = @{
    FilePath = 'msiexec.exe'
    ArgumentList = @(
        '/i',
        'C:\Files\Installer.msi',
        'LOCALIP="127.0.0.1"',
        'USERNAME="username1"'
    )
    Wait = $True
}
Start-Process @InstallerArgs
```

Answer (score 10):

**[Splatting (`@<varName>`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) isn't supported as a parameter *value*** (argument); instead, the hashtable that is splatted *itself* represents a set of parameter *name-value pairs*.

<sup>[Olaf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011753/45375), by contrast, demonstrates proper use of splatting, where the hashtable contains the parameter name-value pairs for `Start-Process` *as a whole*, with the pass-through-to-`msiexec` parameters specified as an array in the `ArgumentList` hashtable entry.</sup>

If you do want to maintain just the pass-through-to-`msiexec` arguments in a separate data structure, use an *array* and *pass it as such*, given that `-ArgumentList` indeed expects a string *array* as its argument (`[string[]]`):

```
$InstallerArgs = @(
    "DATABASENAME=my_database"
    "LOCALIP=127.0.0.1"
    "USERNAME=username1"
    "/i"
    "C:\Files\Installer.msi"
)

# Note: NO splatting
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $InstallerArgs -Wait
```

The above ends up executing the following:

```
msiexec.exe DATABASENAME=my_database LOCALIP=127.0.0.1 USERNAME=username1 /i C:\Files\Installer.msi
```

Note that, due to a long-standing *bug*,  **any values that need *double-quoting* - typically, because they have embedded *whitespace* - must explicitly specify  *embedded, escaped* double quotes as well** (`` `" ``); e.g.,

```
"`"C:\Files A\Installer.msi`""
```

This would result in `msiexec ... "C:\Files A\Installer.msi"` getting passed through.

The problem still exists as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0, and may never be fixed in order to preserve backward compatibility. However, a new parameter may be provided to provide the correct behavior - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

---

**Caveat re splatting with *external programs*:**

**When splatting with *hashtables* (rather than arrays), PowerShell translates the hashtable entries into

`-<key>:<value>` arguments** - note the `:` - which works well with *PowerShell* commands, but may not conform to the argument syntax expected by external utilities such as `msiexec`.
[GitHub issue #9343](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9343) suggests that the format be changed to separating with a *space* (using separate arguments; `-<key> <value>`).

A simple example:

```
# Define hashtable with parameter name-value pairs.
$htParams = @{
   foo = 'bar none'  # parameter -foo with value 'bar none'
}

# Pass the hashtable via splatting (note the use of @ instead of $).
baz.exe @htParams
```

`baz.exe` would then see the following argument:

```
-foo:"bar none"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need `Start-Process`. Remember: PowerShell is a shell; it can run commands you type, just like `cmd.exe`.

```
msiexec /i C:\Files\Installer.msi DATABASENAME=my_database LOCALIP=127.0.0.1 USERNAME=username1
```

If any of the arguments contain spaces, enclose them in `"` characters.

Note: This will run `msiexec` asynchronously (i.e., if you run the command in a script, it will continue to the next line of script without waiting for `msiexec` to complete). If you want to wait for `msiexec` to complete before continuing (i.e., run it synchronously), you can use `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` parameter as noted in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only if you have key=value pairs

```
$params = [string]::Join(" ", ($parameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { $_.Key + "=" + $_.Value }))
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList @InstallerArgs -Wait
```

I'm a c# dev so it may not be a conventional ps style